# How to join single parts of an armature to another rig's bones

Tags: rigging, add-on, bones, faces

I'm fairly new to blender, so far I've managed to generate a full body rig thanks to some addons. Recently I've been wondering to add a detailed facial rig in order to achieve decent face expressions, therefore I thought of addin a face rig to an already generated body rig, but I can't figure out how. Is it possible to take two individual generated rigs and join them together into a single system? How can I attach a face rig to a body rig otherwise? The addon I've been using is AutoRig Pro, but the facial rig I would like to use is Universal Human Face Rig (https://cjones.gumroad.com/l/dOumo).

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have two separate rig systems, one for my character's face and one for the body, they are generated with two different addons, which means I can't generate them together. How can I create a single rig system by joining them together?